# jQuery(..).load(..) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I learn jQuery ajax, but is not working. I'm click on the div, but nothing happens.
Please help me finding where I have made mistake.

js script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#maindiv').click(function(){
        $(this).load('q.txt')
    });
});
```

html page with one div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/aj.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="maindiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

q.txt have a one word.

Comment: If you used `jQery` it's not that strange it doesn't work. Also please consult the console for errors before looking out for an answer elsewhere. It would tell you `$` is not defined.

Comment: How are you clicking on an empty div?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your jQuery file needs to be loaded first. If you look at the console I am sure you would get a $ is not defined error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/aj.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use console and debugger to know what's append on your page. F12 on chrome/firefox, F9 on IE.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the order in which you are including your script source files.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/aj.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

should be changed to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/aj.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Other already mentioned the order of import.

Another problem is that your div `maindiv` is empty. So you can't click on it.

Put something in there :

```
<div id="maindiv">CLICK ME</div>
```